# php get facebook information with user and password

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-sdk-4.0

How do I extract my own Facebook information programmatically (without login dialog) using the PHP Facebook SDK.
 Is there a way to feed facebook with my username and password and get back my profile information?

Comment: There is no official way of doing that.

Comment: There is no way to do it

Answer (score 0):

There are no endpoints for that. If you just want to extract your own info, why don't you use the graph Explorer: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer

You can generate an Access Token with it, and then query for your data.